# Python not writing data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm writing code to build a database where I can input the records from a program and print it when needed. I created a database where I'll save all the data. But when I input the data from the front end, it says "Please check your inputs". This is the code for the part I'm having problem with:

```
def submit_records():
pay_to = values['pay_to']
if pay_to == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing Pay_to')
amount_words = values['amount_words']
if amount_words == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing amount in words')
amount = values['amount']
if amount == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing amount')
address = values['address']
if address == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing address')
purpose = values['purpose']
if purpose == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing purpose')
drawer = values['drawer']
if drawer == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing drawer')
issue_date = values['issue_date']
if issue_date == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing issue_date')
company = values['company']
if company == '':
    sg.popup_error('Missing company')
else:
    try:
        command = "INSERT INTO db_class.box(pay_to, amount_words, amount, address, purpose, drawer, issue_date, company) VALUES (“ + “‘“ + values[‘pay_to’] + “‘“ + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘amount’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘amount_words’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘address’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘purpose’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘drawer’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘issue_date’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘company’] + “’” + “);"
        print(command)
        myCursor.execute(command)
        dbms.commit()
        choice = sg.popup_ok_cancel("Please confirm entry")
        if choice == 'OK':
            clear_records()
            sg.popup_quick('records entered')
        else:
            sg.popup_ok('Edit Entry')
    except:
        sg.popup('Please check your inputs')
```

And this is the message I get from the console:

```
INSERT INTO db_class.box(pay_to, amount_words, amount, address, purpose, drawer, issue_date, company) VALUES (“ + “‘“ + values[‘pay_to’] + “‘“ + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘amount’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘amount_words’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘address’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘purpose’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘drawer’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘issue_date’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘company’] + “’” + “);
```

whereas it should show the inputs I made. Can someone please tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not true syntax i think.

```
INSERT INTO db_class.box(pay_to, amount_words, amount, address, purpose, drawer, issue_date, company) VALUES (“ + “‘“ + values[‘pay_to’] + “‘“ + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘amount’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘amount_words’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘address’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘purpose’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘drawer’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘issue_date’] + “’” + “, “ + “‘“ + values[‘company’] + “’” + “);
```

It should be like this:

```
myCursor.execute("""INSERT INTO db_class.box (pay_to, amount_words, amount, address, purpose, drawer, issue_date, company) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(pay_to, amount_words, amount, address, purpose, drawer, issue_date, company))
```

Would be better to use like this.

Comment: It's good to use parameters, but the list of values must end in a comma, or else use square brackets. Like `(..., company,)` or `[..., company]`.

Comment: Guys, problem solved! There was a connection issue with the database, which i could see in the error message after removing try except. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, using your syntax!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BillKarwin only if a single value is being inserted. So `cursor.execute(sql, ('foo',))` but `cursor.execute(sql, ('foo', 'bar'))`, though a trailing comma in the second case is valid, it is not required.